# How to stop css embedded in an email affecting the whole page

Tags: html, css

My web application records emails sent from third party applications such as Outlook in a timeline using the maillin node.js framework. It all works as intended with one major problem. When a user clicks on an email to view it, the css embedded in the email affects the whole page. I know I could get around this by opening the email in an iframe, or just loading the text. But I was just wondering if there was any other way to isolate the css and stop it infecting the page.
**Edit.**
I should have mentioned the the main application is C# .Net MVC

Comment: If you really want to, you can parse the css strings and prepend a selector to each of them. So `p` becomes `#mail123 p` where `mail123` is id of the root element of an email.

Comment: An iframe is much better, preferably served from an entirely different domain.. Otherwise you're opening yourself up to a number of security issues, where CSS is the least of your problems..

Comment: @xso, I don't think in this case there are major security issues. The emails are sent from the users Email account bcc'ed to the maillin address, intercepted by maillin and recorded in a timeline for the user that sent the email. So in this case they could only attack themselves. However I do take your point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by converting the email to an image, I have a licence for a commercial application that converts html to an image (I won't advertise it), and at the end of the day users just need to see the email. Thanks for your responses anyway.